# cloud code : User can't access object which has ACL for the role it belongs

Tags: parse-platform, role, rbac

The functionality i want to achieve is this

1. When a user registers, two roles(admin, users) are created
2. If the user is an admin he should be able to invite other users to join for the same account with user privilege (non admin)
3. A user who is not admin should not be able to invite people to join

This is how i am trying to achieve this in cloud code

1. Create two roles when an account is created
2. Create two dummy objects with admin and user ACLs, below is the code for these two steps

   ```
   Parse.Cloud.afterSave("account", function(request) {
       var accountName = request.object.get("name");
       //create admin role
       var adminRoleACL = new Parse.ACL();
       adminRoleACL.setPublicReadAccess(false);
       adminRoleACL.setPublicWriteAccess(false);
       var adminRole = new Parse.Role(accountName + ADMINISTRATOR, adminRoleACL);
       adminRole.save();

       //create user role
       var userRoleACL = new Parse.ACL();
       userRoleACL.setPublicReadAccess(false);
       userRoleACL.setPublicWriteAccess(false);
       var userRole = new Parse.Role(accountName + USER, userRoleACL);
       userRole.save();

       // create dummy object for each role with access to only that role
       // we will use these dummy objects in cloud code to figure out whether
       // the user belongs to that group.

       //create dummy for admin
       var dummy = new Dummy();
       dummy.set("name", accountName + ADMINISTRATOR + DUMMY);
       var dummyACL = new Parse.ACL();
       dummyACL.setPublicReadAccess(false);
       dummyACL.setRoleReadAccess(adminRole, true);
       dummy.setACL(dummyACL);
       dummy.save();

       //create dummy for user
       dummy = new Dummy();
       dummy.set("name", accountName + USER + DUMMY);
       dummyACL = new Parse.ACL();
       dummyACL.setPublicReadAccess(false);
       dummyACL.setRoleReadAccess(userRole, true);
       dummy.setACL(dummyACL);
       dummy.save();

   });
   ```

After account is created i add this user to both admin as well as to the user group, here is the code

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addUsersToRole", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var currentUser = request.user;
    var accountName = request.params.accountname;

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
    query.contains("name", accountName);
    query.find({
        success : function(roles) {
            console.log("roles: " + roles.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
                roles[i].getUsers().add(currentUser);
                roles[i].save();
            }
            response.success();
        },
        error : function(error) {
            response.error("error adding to admin role " + error);
        }
    });
});
```

Now when i try to do signup i just want to check if the current user can find the admin dummy object which was created (since the ACL for that was set to be accessed by only admin role). If the object can be read then it should mean that the current user belongs to admin role right? Here is the code

```
Parse.Cloud.define("inviteToSignUp", function(request, response) {
    var userEmail = request.params.email;
    var currentUser = request.user;
    var accountName = currentUser.get("accountname");

    //do it only if the user is admin
    var query = new Parse.Query(Dummy);
    query.equalTo("name", + accountName + ADMINISTRATOR + DUMMY);

    query.first({
        success : function(dummy) {
            if(dummy) {
                sendSignupEmail(userEmail, currentUser, request, response);
            } else {
                response.error("Invitation failed. You don't have the priviledges to add new user. Please contact your administrator'");
            }
        }, 
        error : function(error) {
            response.error("error while inviting users. " + error.message);
        }
    })

});
```

Now the problem is that even though the admin user is logged in the dummy object created doesn't get returned in the query in the above method.
Is there anything i am missing? Is there a better way to achieve this functionality?

I checked the data browser and i can see the two roles being created, the user being member of both the groups. I also see that two dummy objects are created each with these two ACL

1. {"role:XYZ_Administrator":{"read":true}}
2. {"role:XYZ_user":{"read":true}}

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly this issue as well. Did you manage to find a solution that works?

Comment: My issue solved itself after setting the class permissions to "Public" in the data browser. That setting seemed to override any ACL I put on object level, so that was causing my update on the object to fail. Now it respects the object-level ACL and works correctly.